# How can I get the Twitter Bootstrap Task Bar to work correctly in IE7

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap

I recently added a Bootstrap taskbar to an application and it works fine in all modern browsers.

However in IE7 the taskbar becomes very deep vertically and the menu options wrap onto a second line with the "Branding" text on the first line and the menu options on the second line.

Also all the text on the taskbar appears further towards the middle of the page rather than floating left.

Is there any IE7 workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, the issue you describe is likely because IE7 doesn't support @media requests.

You could try [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond) or [css3-media-queries.js](http://code.google.com/p/css3-mediaqueries-js/)

If this looks like it will work for you, conditional comments in the head of your document are one easy way to include this for users with older versions of IE.

I've used this in the past with the following in the head:

```
<!--[if (lt IE 9) & (!IEMobile)]>
<script src="/path-to/js/respond.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Good luck!

**UPDATE**

If I look at the styling for the **navbar > navbar-inner > container** div  its width is set at 940px. This appears to be the source of the problem in older IEs.

See it this works for you.

In the head of your document, after all the other CSS calls add

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie8-and-down.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Then create the new **ie8-and-down.css** stylesheet with the following:

```
.navbar-fixed-top .container{
width:80% !important; /* not sure if you need important but doesn't hurt ;) */
}
```

I'm testing on a Windows installation on a virtual box on a Mac and this works for me ... hope it does the trick for you.

Comment: I will check that out and report back if it fixes the issue. After reading the doco on respond.js etc it does seem plausible that that could be the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately that did not do the trick. The task bar still appears on two lines with the 'branding' on one line and the menu options on the next. The task bar never responds to narrowing by displaying the wee icon on the right. It means that the task bar obscures content on ie7 so I cant really use it. I'm sure there must be a way around this....

Comment: Any chance you can post a link to the page?

Comment: Thanks for taking the effort to check the page. I too am using a Virtual Box installation of XP on my Macbook with IE7... I'll update if I get it to work.

Comment: I added the extra css and it certainly makes it better. However there is still inconsistency between browsers as to when the bar jumps to two lines if there are lots of items and this obscures content. So I have decided not to use it except in non critical areas. Have given the answer a tick as I think it does as well as possible.

Comment: Thanks. What I've done on some sites where IE7 and IE8 were proving to be too difficult to accomodate is create a style targeted at just these browsers and which forces the body > .container or some other element on the page to be say min-width:960px . This disables the responsive grid for just these browsers. Good luck with your site @giorgio